# Login form without database and server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication, win-universal-app, multiplatform

So I am developing a multi-platform app. I want the user to be able to login and register either via social medias (Facebook API) or with a email and/or phone number login.

So my question is: Is this possible without a database and server? I am using a Windows 8 OS PC with Visual Studio Community as IDE, Universal App as framework and C# as programming language.

Also: Is Universal App the best option for developing multi-platform apps? Or is for example Xamarin a better choice?

Regards,

Comment: You could do this with a third-party API, like "Log in via Twitter".

Comment: C# is yet pretty much platform dependent. I suggest you try developing with java or C++ (at least for now they provide much wider platform freedom). You need the API Robert suggested in order to have some login without using a DB of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Without a database? possible: you could store login credentials in files (of course you are creating a "database" in this case).

Without a server, quite difficult. I mean, you should store everything on client side (which is possible if you are talking about a mobile application, more difficult if you are developing a website) or, if you use a third-party API, you should download every time all the information you need to run your app.

Anyway if you don't want a server the only option I am able to think about is to store the credentials on a "file" located in the client.

Regards.